# Working with the entire data in Python Visualizations in Power BI

Tags: python-3.x, powerbi

I have a CSV file with 200 columns loaded into Power BI.

I need to create a visualization showing the columns with #N/A values. For this purpose, I'm using Python Visualization. It prompts me to drag fields into the values area in the visualization to start scripting. But for obvious reasons, I don't want to drag 200 hundred fields manually.

Comment: And why do you have 200 columns?  That's not going to work well for a lot of reasons.

Comment: How many of your columns are actually empty?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft database constraint I cannot get rid of.

Comment: @Peter, empty is not the same as #N/A in my case. Number of columns with #N/A values varies. This functionality is precisely to find which ones of those 200 columns has #N/A values.

Comment: You can pivot columns to rows in Power Query before loading to your Dataset.

Comment: W/o sample data this discussion leads to nowhere.